# cp command to overwrite the destination file which is a symbolic link

Tags: linux, shell, cp

Does cp command have any option to overwrite the destination file which is a symbolic link?

The problem is as follows:

```
[dthnguyen@dthnguyen test]$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dthnguyen dthnguyen 5 Feb 21 09:07 a.txt
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 dthnguyen dthnguyen 7 Feb 21 08:55 b.txt -> ./a.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dthnguyen dthnguyen 5 Feb 21 08:55 c.txt
[dthnguyen@dthnguyen test]$ cp c.txt b.txt
```

After do the copy, a.txt has the content of c.txt, b.txt still links to a.txt. The expected result is a.txt holds the old content, b.txt is a new regular file that has the same content as c.txt.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Tell `cp` to remove it first.

```
cp --remove-destination c.txt b.txt
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this for directories? I tried it with `-r` and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't see this option on OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: This doesn't work under Mac OS for some reason: cp keeps whinging on and on about `illegal option -- -`

Comment: @cjm: Correct. OS X uses BSD `cp`, which has [its own options](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html)

Comment: @Ajedi32  Using `find $dir -type l -delete` to delete the symbolic links before copying,